# error uploading files with python request library to google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm uploading a file to google cloud storage with the [rest api](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics?authuser=1)

with curl it works ok

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @[OBJECT] \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -H "Content-Type: [OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE]" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]"
```

but with python requests post the file is uploaded corrupted

```
import requests
filepath = '/home/user/gcs/image.jpg'
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/****/o?uploadType=media&name=image.jpg'
authorization = 'Bearer ******'

headers = {
    "Authorization": authorization,
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
}

with open(filepath, "rb") as image_file:
    files = {'media.jpeg': image_file}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
    print(r.content)
```

Comment: how big is the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: a image of 11,2 kB

Comment: try  `files = {'media.jpeg': image_file.read()}`

Comment: same error, with or without .read()

Answer (score 4):

The method of upload you are calling requires that the request body contain *only* the data you are uploading. This is what the curl `--data-binary` option does. However `requests.post(files=BLAH)` is *multipart-encoding* your data, which is not what you want.  Instead you want to use the data parameter:

```
with open(filepath, "rb") as image_file:
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=image_file)
    print(r.content)
```